# Order of evaluation in sequence of bitwise OR

Tags: c++, c

Consider following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<uint8_t> rawbytes;
    rawbytes data({0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd});
    rawbytes::iterator data_it = data.begin();

    uint32_t as_int = (*data_it++ << 24 ) | ( *data_it++ << 16 ) | ( *data_it++ << 8 ) | *data_it++;     

    std::cout << std::hex << as_int << std::endl;
}
```

The output from this code is what I was expecting:

```
aabbccdd
```

Actually I wrote similar code and I realized that i'm not sure if it is guaranteed to work.

My doubts are placed in line:

```
uint32_t as_int = (*data_it++ << 24 ) | ( *data_it++ << 16 ) | ( *data_it++ << 8 ) | *data_it++;
```

If it is guaranteed that evaluation will be performed from left to right, so it means in this order? :

```
1: (*data_it++ << 24 )
2: (*data_it++ << 16 )
3: (*data_it++ << 8 )
4: *data_it++
```

My understanding is following: 
From "|" operator point of view, it doesn't matter which side of operator will be performed first. 
So it means that this code work as (primarily) expected, but actually by accident.

So my question is, if it is guaranteed, and why ?

Comment: Multiple ++ on a single variable within a single expression is UB in C. Later versions of C++ might have defined it but it's still a bad idea for backward compatibility reasons.

Comment: `data_it++` occurs 3 times between sequence points, and what is not defined is *exactly when* each one is implemented, except some time between accessing the variable and the next sequence point.  So all 3 increments might not be done until the next sequence point, or each one just after accessing `data_it`, or in any combination, so the expression is *undefined*, even before considering the `|` you asked about. Adding parentheses won't affect that.

Comment: Just use `rawbytes[0]`, `rawbytes[1]`, etc instead of incrementing the iterator in the expression and avoid the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I have learn't more than I expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no such guarantees.

Unlike its cousin `||`, `|` is **not** a sequencing point.

The behaviour of your program is undefined.